# How to find a solution for my Gin problem?

Tags: c#, algorithm, gwt-gin

Recently I was playing a game of Gin with my [grandmother](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gin_rummy). We played a whole afternoon and as far as I can remember, I didn't won a single game.

So I told here that it with the help of computers it could become a much better player. She couldn't believe how computers could be useful there and that's why I want to demonstrate it.

I already implemented part of the logic, but now I have the problem that my solver is really not so sexy because he mainly is based on a brute force method. That is I calculated all the possibilities, score them according to the chances for a win and choose the best one. Is there any more sophisticated approach?

I'm talking about standard Gin. The implementation is done in C#.

Comment: You forgot the important part: does your program consistently beat your grand mother?

Comment: Find someone with a Tonic problem.  Oh - wait - cards.  Nevermind.

Comment: Best legitimate SO question title ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% familiar with gin, but one thing to keep in mind is each strategy can be broken.

When you play, you have to play multiple players. Do they both have the same strategy? Do they have different strategy? If we played you might beat me in gin, but I might beat your grandma. How does your grandma know how to play? If you were given the same hand she does, how would she play it differently than yours? Yes you can take a look at the statistics, but your grandma doesn't play by statistics - she plays by experience. If you want to make it more sophisticated ask yourself "How can I factor experience into the hand?"

Comment: I'd like to see a proof of that. Many games, like Chess, have an optimal strategy ('perfect play'), and any variation from that disadvantages the deviating player. Gin might well be one of those games.

Comment: Chess does not have an optimal strategy. You must react to your opponent. Consider this 'optimal strategy' played against itself. Who wins?

Comment: In chess?  Maybe player 1, but it's probably a tie.  The optimal strategy will encode a reaction to every possible move that your opponent can make.  The difference between Chess and Gin (if Gin == Gin Rummy) is that chess is perfect information, whereas Gin is not.  But the while the game theory might be interesting, I don't think it's actually helpful to the OP.

Comment: It is a well known conjecture that 2 perfect Chess players should always draw. Bobby Fischer himself joked that if he played god, he bet that he could draw the game. http://articles.cnn.com/2010-07-06/us/bobby.fischer.profile_1_regina-fischer-shelby-lyman-fischer-family?_s=PM:US

Comment: @rrenaud But just because a game isn't perfect knowledge doesn't mean it doesn't have an ideal strategy. Some games, like paper scissors rock, have no optimal strategy, but many do, and I'm not convinced Gin isn't one.

Comment: @glowcoder: according to the Wikipedia article, Gin rummy is a two player game, so you do _not_ have to play multiple players.

Comment: @Svante... if you have 2 players, you have multiple players. My "When you play you have to play multiple players" could be rephrased as "When you simulate the game you must take into account both players"